# Google map api v3 projection?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I would like to find out what projection is google map using is it EPSG:4326 or P900913 ? Also if you use the drawing tools what projection coordinates are generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EPSG3857](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/EPSG:3857) is the official designation.

> Interactive web maps are using "Spherical Mercator" system which uses Mercator projection on
>   the sphere instead of WGS84 ellipsoid.

[More information](http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/google-projection/)

Answer (score 1):

> Google Maps uses the Mercator projection for this purpose
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#WorldCoordinates

Comment: Commonly what projection does google map use when it is translating any of the lat long value on its map?

Comment: @What EPSG value does that represents is 4326 or 900913

Comment: > Google Earth uses the WGS84 projection which has the code EPSG:4326 whereas Google Maps uses EPSG:3857 (alias EPSG:900913).
(http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21427/why-are-the-tile-coordinates-different-in-google-maps-and-google-earth)

Comment: so can I say whatever drawing I do on google map is eventually in EPSG:3857? And whatever lat long value I try to project on the map is eventually converted into EPSG:3857 for google map.