# Cannot load geojson from source using Google Maps Data Layer

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geojson

I have obtained a geoJSON dataset from a [publicly available dataset here](http://data.gov.au/dataset/buildings/resource/76ad1b7b-d3b8-4944-ac85-f95929fadec7) which I have [saved here](http://jsonblob.com/53e463bce4b0e48f0ccd3229).

When I loaded this data into the Google Maps Data Layer from a file on my system:

```
var goldCoastData = new google.maps.Data({
    map: map,
    style: {
        icon: 'images/marker_gc.png',
        strokeColour: '#0b2430',
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        fillColor: '#ff534f',
        fillOpacity: 1
    }
});

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'scripts/datasets/goldCoast_buildings.json',
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function (data) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    goldCoastData.addGeoJson(data);
});
```

The data is not displayed on the map.I ran the following checks on the data:

1. jsonlint(successfull)
2. geojsonhint(successful)
3. [`geojsonlint`](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1gotnhcg6660fca/Screenshot%202014-08-08%2011.44.52.png) inconclusive/failure???
4. [drag and drop](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-dragndrop) failure

Comment: The latitudes and longitudes in that data are in the wrong projection to be used on Google Maps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15015946/google-map-api-v3-projection

Comment: As geocodezip has said, that is the wrong projection, EPSG:28354, which is local to Australia, whereas Google Maps requires EPSG:3857, which is spherical mercator and covers the globe. You will need to reproject from one to the other. You can use http://trac.osgeo.org/proj4js/wiki/UserGuide for this. I know how to do this in OpenLayers directly, but not in Google Maps, so I can't give you a working example.

Comment: Could you provide me with the string or a resource/steps to follow for creating the string for `EPSG:28354` so that I can use it as a [`named projection`](https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js#using)

Comment: As you recommended, use proj4 to convert it to [this](http://jsonblob.com/53e5db51e4b0bab7bd401bda),will this data work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the `geoJson` added to the `google maps` `Data layer` needs to use the projection `EPSG:4326` in order to work.I could obtain the data from the datasets in this format using the &SrsName=EPSG:4326 at the end of the url.

[This links to data from the question in the correct format](http://data.gov.au/geoserver/buildings/wfs?request=GetFeature&typeName=da4f31ac_2716_4eca_b067_359f0b868d3c&outputFormat=json&SrsName=EPSG:4326)

From the comments to the question by @geocodezip and @John Barça state that Google uses EPSG:3857 so this must be some kind of a quirk,hopefully.