# bokeh map plot. lat/long to x and y

Tags: python, google-maps, gis, bokeh

I am trying to plot some circle markers in bokeh, python on stamer toner map.
I have locations from google map api in such format:

```
 latitude 41.552164 longitude 44.990961
```

But the bokeh map plot gets data points in X and Y coordinate format.
How can I transform these lat/long coordinates to X and Y?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266809/convert-from-latitude-longitude-to-x-y) can help you

Comment: I think it's close to my question but doesn't answer fully. They talk about distance and I want just point translation from lat/long to x,y.

Answer (score 5):

your question is a little vague on what exactly you are trying to do and a code example would help give a better answer.

Generally when trying to plot geographical data obtained by online sources, you will have data in a coordinate system (WGS84) with latitude being the y and longitude being the x. Bokeh can plot longitude and latitude simply by specifying the proper names in the ColumnDataSource.

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure


longitude  = [44.990961]
latitude = [41.552164]

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(longitude=longitude, latitude=latitude))

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
p.circle(x='longitude', y='latitude', source=source)
show(p)
```

---

If truly your question is related to a coordinate transformation of your data, it will be difficult to answer your question without more details. I recommend you take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection to understand map projections.

If you need to convert the longitude/latitude coordinates into a different coordinates system. You can use the `pyproj` package.

```
import pyproj

project_projection = pyproj.Proj("+init=EPSG:4326")  # wgs84
google_projection = pyproj.Proj("+init=EPSG:3857")  # default google projection

longitude = [44.990961]
latitude = [41.552164]

x, y = pyproj.transform(google_projection, project_projection, longitude, latitude)

print(x, y)
```

---

Reference for the google projection [Google map api v3 projection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15015946/google-map-api-v3-projection)

Comment: If you don't want to have to us the pyproj library then it actually is pretty easy to convert the coordinates in pure python, as described [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247871/convert-gps-coordinates-to-web-mercator-epsg3857-using-python-pyproj)

Answer (score 1):

in order to easily transform from longitude/latitude (EPSG:4326) into another projection (for example [WebMercator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator#EPSG:3857) EPSG:3857, used by GoogleMaps AFAIK), I would recommend `pyproj` package in combination with `shapely`, for example:

```
from functools import partial
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.ops import transform
import pyproj

pnt = transform(
    partial(
        pyproj.transform,
        pyproj.Proj(init='EPSG:4326'),
        pyproj.Proj(init='EPSG:3857')), Point(44.990961, 41.552164))

print(pnt.x, pnt.y)
```